# Regex replace that preserves capitalization

Tags: regex, replace

Is it possible to replace `"this"` with `"that"` and `"This"` with `"That"` in one regex?

Perl extensions and other special tricks are allowed.

Edit: It's too easy if the replacement starts with the same letter. How about `server` to `node` and `Server` to `Node`

Assuming I only care about the first letter and using Perl, I came up with:

```
s/(s)erver/($1 eq uc $1 ? "N" : "n") . "ode"/ie
```

Comment: I have tried `s/this/that/i`, but it converts both to `that` of course.

Comment: Regex isn't for replacing anything. It's for searching.

Comment: Ok, but most languages' regex systems includes a replacement functionality, with `$1`, `$2` etc.

Comment: Your question is flagged as `regex`. Please read [ask].

Comment: No need to be rude. What is the tag for regex replacing then?

Comment: You can combine tags. At least add technology tag.

Comment: it might work to store the capitalization state in one step as a vector of 0s and 1s, run your replace and then recapitalize. The problem becomes if your replace length is <> your find length. Probably manageable though. A solution depends on what language you are using for the replace

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do it like:

```
var z = "This this";
z.replace(/([Tt])his/g, '$1hat');
```

result would be: `That that`